# delete or change commits after pushing to github

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

I made my commits and pushed to github. Then, I realized that one is a wrong file and I forgot to add a new file.
I would like to either completely undo or delete my pushed commit or add and delete the files from my pushed commits.
Which is easier and what should I do?(I am the only one working on this repo so no one hasn't pulled or changed my commits.)

Comment: You should be able to push a second time and overwrite the commit. Did you try that?

Comment: pushing for a second time will not overwrite my previous commit but add a new commit on top. I would like to completely delete my previous pushed commit.

Comment: It's a bad practice to modify or delete public commits.  It's better to revert the bad commit and add a new one on top of it. If you have your heart set on changing it, modify the commit locally and then do a force push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways.

The first is the way "Lajos" mentioned - squash the commits into one.  This has an impact on the version history, and rewriting public version histories is (as everyone else has pointed out) a bad thing.  It can cause all kinds of nasty, and even if you're the only one that touches the repo it's still a good idea to get into the habit of not rewriting public version histories.

The better way is to do a reversion (git revert).  This creates new commits that reverse the changes of the undesirable commit and does so by adding a new commit to the history rather than attempting to modify the existing public history.

See [git-revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

1. Create a new commit with the additional files.
2. Squash the last two commits into one. (git rebase -i HEAD~2)
3. And push this branch to github again. (git push -f ...)

Possibly there are other ways.

But as other mentioned it isn't a good practice to rewrite publicly accessible history...